# How to get percentage in TSQL when dividing 2 integers?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to display this division as a percent.

```
SELECT a * 100/b
FROM myTable
WHERE condition
```

Here, for instance, **a = 170**, **b = 288**. `a / b = 0.590277777778`.

I'd like to return `59,02`. What I'm getting is only `59`. How to get both parts?

Comment: Introduce a decimal, E.g. `select 170 * 100.0 / 288` to avoid the integer math you are seeing.

Comment: `100.0` is returning `59.0277777777779`

Comment: Yes. If you want 2 dp `select cast(170 * 100.0 / 288 as decimal(5, 2))` or if you want the value as a string use `str()`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sql Server sees only integer arguments and returns integer result. Make one of two first arguments numeric / decimal

```
select a * 100./b
```

or

```
select cast(cast(a as decimal(18,4)) * 100/b as decimal(18,2))
```

this will not help:

```
select a/b*100.
```

because of the order of operations first opeation ( division )is still integer.

Test case to play with

```
declare @a int=170,
        @b int=288;

select  cast(@a as decimal)*100/@b   --59.02777777777
      , @a*100./@b  --59.02777777777
      , cast (@a*100./@b as decimal(18,2)) --59.03
```

Comment: I would suggest that float is a terrible choice. The float datatype is an approximate datatype, not an exact one. As such not all values can be stored in a float. And this really comes to light when you do division.

Comment: Is there a way to choose the number of digits after the dot?

Comment: Using just `SELECT  a* 100.0/b` was returning `59.00`. Defining a local variable `@myvar AS DECIMAL(18, 2)` and assigning the result to that variable `SELECT myvar = a* 100.0/b` returns `59.03`.