calculating a value in a query
I'm trying to calculate a value in a query and if I do it one way it works but when I do it the way i need it to work I always come up with 0
This is the result of my query
enrolled AssessedCount  (No column name)
806324    448418    0
My query
SELECT e.enrolled, a. AssessedCount, AssessedCount/enrolled
FROM #Assessement a
CROSS JOIN #Enrolled e
If I switch the formula to Enrolled/AssessedCount I get results but I need the percentage the other way. TIA
I've tried several different ways before getting to this one where I have the values in 2 sepearate tables then combining then into one table.
Final result is I need to put the results as a row in a Power BI Report Builder report
The results need to go into this query to update the last row so when the report runs all the information is there.
In the report builder I just have the Group Colum and Group Row so can't tell it in the report to cacluate. What I'm wanting is the final report that Students Assessed is divided by Students Enrolled to get the participation rate. I need it for both columns but if I can get it for one I can make it work for the other one.
TIA
Group                         AllStudents   IEPStudents
Students Assessed            448418          85749
Students Enrolled             806324         159448
Assessment Participation Rate      0               NULL

Please provide example  #Assessement and #Enrolled tables and a table showing your desired output.

Maybe this fiddle will help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/ykiXHsJ9

What data type is Enrolled and AssessedCount?

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396087/how-to-get-percentage-in-tsql-when-dividing-2-integers

I think the simplest answer is to cast one of them as a float (your method may vary by DB):
SELECT e.enrolled, a.AssessedCount, AssessedCount/CAST(enrolled as FLOAT)
  FROM #Assessement a CROSS JOIN #Enrolled e


I think this fiddle demonstrates what Carter is suggesting https://dbfiddle.uk/T8iIs5iu

Very awesome dbfiddle @BartMcEndree ! I had no idea there was even a tool as neat as this thanks!

See also https://tableconvert.com/csv-to-sql  for quickly taking examples from questions and converting them into Create Table + Insert commands.
